# Realm: How to catch the exception when the Object with same Primary key value is tried to add and display an error message

Tags: ios, swift, realm

For now I am using this fetching with Predicate to know if the same primary key value is already available:

Category class:

```
class Category: Object
{
    dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }    
}
```

Validating if Category Object with primary key (name) value already exists.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", newCategoryName)
let realm = try Realm()

let categories = realm.objects(Category).filter(predicate).sorted("name")

if categories.count > 0
{
    //Duplicate Object with newCategoryName found
}
```

Is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you use it to check if there's already an object with that primary key:

```
let category = Realm().objectForPrimaryKey(Category.self, key: newCategoryName)

if (category != nil) {
    //Duplicate Object with newCategoryName found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Realm.add(_:update:)` or `Realm.create(_:update:)` with `update == true` to update an existing object with the same primary key value. Alternatively, you can use `Realm.objectForPrimaryKey(_:key:)` to fetch an existing object from the primary key.

Comment: But how do I know it is a duplicate?

Comment: If `Realm.objectForPrimaryKey` returns a non-nil value, that would mean you already have an object with that primary key persisted in the Realm.